# Operation behind MySQL Select SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a MySQL table with this structure

- ID [pk, MediumInt]
- UID [MediumInt]
- Author [TinyText]
- TAGS [TinyText]
- Title [TinyText]
- Text [Text]

When I perform a search or select on ID,UID,Tags or all of these 3 will MySQL also load the Text field in memory? [which i did not specified in the SQL]

Example->

```
SQL1-> Select ID,UID,Tags order by Tags
SQL2-> Select ID,UID,Tags where UID=1
SQL3-> Select ID,UID,Tags,Title where UID=1 and Tags=Hello
SQL4-> Select ID,UID,Tags,Title where Tags=Hello
```

[will MySQL load Text column too in memory for the above queries ?]

Comment: Sounds like selection(in MySQL, WHERE) executes before projection(in MySQL, SELECT).  How did you check if the Text field was loaded into memory or not?

Comment: I dont know and thats why i'm asking :)

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm -- read here -- selection does occur before projection.  So, yes, Text field gets loaded into the memory whether or not you ask for it.

Comment: @vpit3833 - yes, that's the order that the operations have to appear to occur in, but different SQL products are allowed to apply optimizations as they see fit, provided the overall result is "as if" that was what happened. What happens specifically in MySQL, I couldn't say, and may depend on which storage engine is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

In MySQL, `TEXT` and `BLOB` fields are **not** stored in the rows, so a read from them requires a separate table lookup.
So **no** MySQL will not read the `text` field in memory when processing the above queries.
See: http://nicj.net/2011/01/20/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance

You have another problem with this query though, **it's slow** because:

1. `TEXT` and `BLOB` fields are not stored in the row, so MySQL needs to do a separate lookup for each `TEXT` field.
2. The MEMORY engine does not support `BLOB` or `TEXT` fields, so **if** MySQL needs to use a temporary table to resolve the query, it will store the intermediate table **on disk** slowing things way down.

**Advice**
Don't use `tinytext` for the columns `Author`, `Tags` and `Title`. These would work faster using a varchar.
Note that `text` is a reserved word, so you'll need to enclose the field name in backticks `` ` ``.

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html